# Run function VBA with cell color change

Tags: excel, vba, function

I don't know if it possible: I have a VBA function which I call from cells.
The function is using the background color of cells.

The issue is that the function, like all functions,  is automatically running and updating concerned cells only after leaving the writing cursor on the cell.
If I just change the background color without double clicking on the cell, it is not running.

Do you know if there is a way to change this?
Thanks

Comment: This won't work. What you can do: add a new column that takes values from which you can derive the cell color by conditional formatting. Your function would then not check for the background color but for the value of the new cell. If you change this value the result of the formula will change.

Comment: Last sentence is wrong - should be: If you change this value the result of the **function** will change.

Comment: This *"The function is using the background color of cells"* is what you did wrong! Color should never transport information, color should **always** only be the result of an information (and only for better visibility). So always transport information by values in cells never by color. • Do some resarch on conditional formatting if you want to change the color according to the cell value automatically (a function cannot change the cell color).

Comment: It can be imagined such a pseudo event, able to be triggered by the cell interior color change, using a class which creates a `CommandBar` trying to define an event based on its `OnUpdate` one... I can show such a code, but I think there are other simpler methods to achieve what you need. That's why, it should be good to better describe what you want accomplishing and in what circumstances...

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you included the actual code you're using.