# Can I set the colour of one cell to change with an input cell colour?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, conditional-formatting

I want to set the cell colour for a range of cells to equal the cell color of another cell (as an input cell)

For example, if i turn the input cell to red fill, i want all the other various ranges, say B2:Z2 on multiple other tabs to also turn red.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365125/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-excel-cells-using-vba), reading the color value is just as simple as giving it to a cell. There is no event that will trigger with color change however, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658082/run-function-vba-with-cell-color-change) to give you more of an idea how to handle it (conditional formatting). What you can do is check in the Selection_Change event (and Deactivate event) if two cells (check-cell and other cell in your range) have different color.